# Is web scraping content from the web illegal ?

Tags: copyright, terms-of-service

I would like to create a service that gathers contents from other news websites and display them in a way that may not necessarily be violating the source's terms.

The intent is to aggregate data that I cannot provide myself (lack of resources, knowledge, time) but at the same time I want to respect the source by only showing the opening paragraph (RSS style) and link back to the source.

I keep having a bad conscience about this approach, but then again I'd need to aggregate the data in some way or another.

I keep reading that web scraping is ubiquitous nowadays and that everybody does it.

Comment: Maybe some related questions can also be found on other sites. I found two somewhat similar posts. [Is this web scraping and is it legal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786556/is-this-web-scraping-and-is-it-legal) and [How (il)legal is it to get data from a 100% accessible but not “exposed” API](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/73908/how-illegal-is-it-to-get-data-from-a-100-accessible-but-not-exposed-api).

Comment: Hint: search engines.